# Minimum sum partition of an array

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Problem Statement:**

Given an array, the task is to divide it into two sets S1 and S2 such that the absolute difference between their sums is minimum.

**Sample Inputs**,

`[1,6,5,11]` => `1`. The 2 subsets are `{1,5,6}` and `{11}` with sums being `12` and `11`. Hence answer is `1`.

`[36,7,46,40]` => `23`. The 2 subsets are `{7,46}` and `{36,40}` with sums being `53` and `76`. Hence answer is `23`.

**Constraints**

> 1 <= size of array <= 50
>
> 1 <= a[i] <= 50

**My Effort:**

```
int someFunction(int n, int *arr) {
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), compare);// sorted it for simplicity
    int i, j;
    int dp[55][3000]; // sum of the array won't go beyond 3000 and size of array is less than or equal to 50(for the rows) 

    // initialize
    for (i = 0; i < 55; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3000; ++j)
            dp[i][j] = 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum += arr[i];

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j <= sum; ++j) {
            dp[i + 1][j + 1] = max(dp[i + 1][j], dp[i][j + 1]);
            if (j >= arr[i])
                dp[i + 1][j + 1] = max(dp[i + 1][j + 1], arr[i] + dp[i][j + 1 - arr[i]]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j <= sum; ++j)
            printf("%d ", dp[i + 1][j + 1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;// irrelevant for now as I am yet to understand what to do next to get the minimum. 
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Let's say for input `[1,5,6,11]`, I am getting the `dp` array output as below.

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
0 1 1 1 1 5 6 7 7 7 7 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 
0 1 1 1 1 5 6 7 7 7 7 11 12 12 12 12 16 17 18 18 18 18 22 23
```

Now, how to **decide** the 2 subsets to get the minimum?

P.S - I have already seen this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/) but explanation is not good enough for a DP beginner like me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to solve `subset sum` problem for `SumValue = OverallSum / 2`

Note that you don't need to solve any optimization problem (as using `max` operation in your code reveals).

Just fill linear table (1D array `A`) of size (SumValue + 1) with possible sums, get the closest to the last cell non-zero result (scan A backward) wint index `M` and  calculate final result as  `abs(OverallSum - M - M)`.

To start, set 0-th entry to 1.
Then for every source array item `D[i]` scan array `A` from the end to beginning:

```
A[0] = 1;
for (i = 0; i < D.Length(); i++)
  {
    for (j = SumValue; j >= D[i]; j--)  
      {
        if (A[j - D[i]] == 1)   
       // we can compose sum j from D[i] and previously made sum
             A[j] = 1;
       }
   }
```

For example `D = [1,6,5,11]` you have `SumValue = 12`, make array `A[13]`, and calculate possible sums

```
A array after filling: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

working Python code:

```
def besthalf(d):
    s = sum(d)
    half = s // 2
    a = [1] + [0] * half
    for v in d:
        for j in range(half, v - 1, -1):
            if (a[j -v] == 1):
                a[j] = 1
    for j in range(half, 0, -1):
        if (a[j] == 1):
            m = j
            break
    return(s - 2 * m)

print(besthalf([1,5,6,11]))
print(besthalf([1,1,1,50]))
>>1
>>47
```

Comment: I have solved the `subset sum` problem and it was easier for me since we have to search a given sum. In this case, we don't what the sum is and we have to find 2 closest possible sums.  Also, regarding the 1D array filling, I am not quite sure if this would work with all cases. Let me check and tell you.

Comment: Can you let me know about how it would work with `[1,1,1,50]` ? Because `SumValue` is `27` and the closest non cell result will be 3 and when we evaluate for `50`, it will go out of array bounds. The answer to this be `47` from subsets `{1,1,1}` and `{50}`.

Comment: We won't treat value 50 due to `j > = D[i]` condition. M index (possible sum closest to 27) will be 3, so result is `53 - 3 - 3 = 47`

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot :) This works !! So, the idea is to get one of the possible subsets closest to `SumValue` and then calculate the difference from `OverallSum` to get the minimum difference. Brilliant. This also eliminates the need to hunt for the other subset.

Comment: Can you let me know how did you derive this? Is it intuitive? Can you refer me any links where I can master this art? I have tried topcoder, codechef but they aren't so friendly.

Comment: AFAIR, similar problem of coin changing I did elaborate myself before I know anything about DP. Just thinking - how to compose sum `S`? From coin `С[i]` and sum `S-C[i], then repeating for `S-C[i]` and another coins.

Comment: Note - you can improve this solution as exercise to provide also the best subset itself, Think how to store information about used items in the same array and retrieve them at the end.

Comment: @vivek_23 You created some additional storage structures to retrieve resulting set. But it is possible to save description of one resulting set in the same `dp` array. Now we use `dp` as boolean, but it is int...

Comment: Can you guide me on this? Even though `dp` is int, we are kind of using it as a boolean itself with `0` and `1`. So, how do we retrieve the set from this? Do we use recursion on the first non zero cell and backtrace to get the elements?

Comment: OK. `arr` values are positive numbers. `if(dp[j-arr[i]] > 0){dp[j] = arr[i];}`  Yes, then backtrace

Answer (score 1):

```
I'll convert this problem to subset sum problem
let's  take array int[] A = { 10,20,15,5,25,33 };
it should be divided into {25 20 10} and { 33 20 } and answer is 55-53=2

Notations : SUM == sum of whole array
            sum1 == sum of subset1
            sum2 == sum of subset1

step 1: get sum of whole array  SUM=108
step 2:  whichever way we divide our array into two part one thing will remain true
          sum1+ sum2= SUM
step 3: if our intention is to get minimum sum difference then 
sum1 and sum2 should be near SUM/2 (example sum1=54 and sum2=54 then diff=0 )

steon 4: let's try combinations


        sum1 = 54 AND sum2 = 54   (not possible to divide like this) 
        sum1 = 55 AND sum2 = 53   (possible and our solution, should break here)
        sum1 = 56 AND sum2 = 52  
        sum1 = 57 AND sum2 = 51 .......so on
        pseudo code
        SUM=Array.sum();
        sum1 = SUM/2;
        sum2 = SUM-sum1;
        while(true){
          if(subSetSuMProblem(A,sum1) && subSetSuMProblem(A,sum2){
           print "possible"
           break;
          }
         else{
          sum1++;
          sum2--;
         }
         }
```

Java code for the same

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MinimumSumSubsetPrint {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = {10, 20, 15, 5, 25, 32};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        sum += A[i];
    }
    subsetSumDynamic(A, sum);

}

private static boolean subsetSumDynamic(int[] A, int sum) {
    int n = A.length;
    boolean[][] T = new boolean[n + 1][sum + 1];


    // sum2[0][0]=true;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        T[i][0] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
            if (A[i - 1] > j) {
                T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j];
            } else {
                T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j] || T[i - 1][j - A[i - 1]];
            }
        }
    }

    int sum1 = sum / 2;
    int sum2 = sum - sum1;
    while (true) {
        if (T[n][sum1] && T[n][sum2]) {
            printSubsets(T, sum1, n, A);
            printSubsets(T, sum2, n, A);
            break;
        } else {
            sum1 = sum1 - 1;
            sum2 = sum - sum1;
            System.out.println(sum1 + ":" + sum2);
        }
    }


    return T[n][sum];
}

private static void printSubsets(boolean[][] T, int sum, int n, int[] A) {
    List<Integer> sumvals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = n;
    int j = sum;
    while (i > 0 && j > 0) {
        if (T[i][j] == T[i - 1][j]) {
            i--;
        } else {
            sumvals.add(A[i - 1]);

            j = j - A[i - 1];
            i--;

        }
    }


    System.out.println();
    for (int p : sumvals) {
        System.out.print(p + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Java code if anyone is interested but the idea remains the same as what [@MBo has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51711581/4964822)

```
class Solution{
    public int minDifference(int arr[]) { 
        int sum = 0;
        for(int x : arr) sum += x;
        int half = (sum >> 1) + (sum & 1);
        boolean[] sums = new boolean[half + 1];
        sums[0] = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
            if(arr[i] > half) continue;
            for(int j = half; j >= arr[i]; --j){
                if(sums[j - arr[i]]){
                    sums[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = sums.length - 1; i >= 1; --i){
            if(sums[i]) return Math.abs((sum - i) - i);
        }
        
        return sum; // for arrays like [2] or [100] etc
    } 
}
```